# in EXCEL every number in column A is part of or equal to a number in column B , How find full number from column B Base on numbers in column A?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
Column A  Column B
1245      10005489
5489      4875784568
1236      254240003
          011245
          51236
          452682
          1236
```

the required result :

```
Column C
011245
10005489
1236
```

as you see there are tow numbers in column B that contains "1236" but I want the closest match which is 1236 itself.

I've tried VLOOKUP but didn't get the result I want

Comment: Perhaps try find() with and without wildcards and an if() to do them in order.

Answer (score 4):

I'm just anticipating that you want the closest match by length:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=MAP(A1:A3,LAMBDA(x,LET(r,B1:B7,y,IFERROR(FIND(x,r),)*r,@SORT(FILTER(r,y,"")))))
```

**Note**: If you'd be looking for say '99' and values in column B:B would be '991' and '199' (in that order), it would now return '991' as they are the same length and this value would come first. If that is not what you want then maybe:

```
=MAP(A1:A3,LAMBDA(x,LET(r,B1:B7,y,IFERROR(FIND(x,r),)*r,z,--FILTER(r,y),XLOOKUP(--x,z,z,"",1))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, not as neat as the others but may be worth a look:

[image]

And with the 4th value set as text ie " '011245 ", mine still works, notice it is now to the left of the cell:

[image]

Formula in cell C4:

```
INDEX($B$4:$B$10,MATCH(MINIFS(I4:I10,I4:I10,">"&0),I4:I10,0))
```

Formula in cell I4:

```
IFERROR(FIND(A4,B4:B10,1),0)
```

Answer (score 2):

`=TOCOL(B1:B7/MMULT(--ISNUMBER(FIND(TOROW(A1:A3),B1:B7)),ROW(A1:A3)^0),3)`

Or more dynamic:

```
=LET(a,A1:A3,
     b,B1:B7,
TOCOL(b/MMULT(--ISNUMBER(FIND(TOROW(a),b)),a^0),3))
```

Where Mmult checks for the occurrence in range `b`. The value in `b` is divided by the boolean of the Mmult and TOCOL filters out the falses (which result in divide by zero error)

Note that this solution returns *all* values in column Nthat contain any of the values of column A

Comment: Aren't you returning too many values?

Comment: The title says something else than the expected result. I calculated all values where we find any of the numbers of column A

Comment: I see, some people write confusing questions unfortunately. I went with *"As you see there are two numbers in column B that contains "1236" but I want the closest match which is 1236 itself"*.

Comment: I have to confess I didn't even read that  your solution is perfect in that case

Comment: @JvdV I went with the closest as well, but I could use max() in place of min() and get both with my answer.

Comment: @JvdV ok, and tested for that, works just the same and edited with second image to prove it.

Comment: @SolarMike, yeah I misread your answer at first. I just ran it myself and it works! Just that when OP would look for '99' and '991' and '199' would both be hits, you would return '991'. It just depends on what OP defines as 'closests' in that case. Integerwise or lengthwise. Either way, you all have my kudo's anyways =)

Comment: @JvdV I think we all did well, neat challenge :)

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something, or can we not just use a good old-fashioned `VLOOKUP` here?

`=0+VLOOKUP("*"&A1:A3&"*",""&SORT(B1:B7),1,0)`

Comment: Sir, i tried to evaluate the formula, but what is the use of the empty string added to each number, I don't know the use case so i am asking.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Have you tried without ""?

Comment: WIldcards don't work with numerics.